# Angular Filter: Fiddle and my code have different results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a filter in my mean.io project. As I was having problems I tested it doing a simple version in a fiddle.

But the fiddle filter is working great, and not my project...

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zkwbbt0x/

Here is my project code:

```
 {{global.user._id}} <!-- Working ok, I get the good user Id -->
  <div class="articles list-group liste-articles">
     <a data-ng-repeat="art in articles | contains:global.searchText | filter:{ 'user._id': global.user._id}:true" ng-click="selectByArticle(art)" class="list-group-item lien-article" ng-class="{sel: art._id == article._id}">
     {{art.user._id}}</a> <!-- Working ok, I get the good article.user Id -->
  </div>
```

My project is a little more complicated but I can't find where it is wrong...

Any idea?

#### ADDITIONAL INFO/

in my crontroller I have:

```
$scope.global = Global;
```

My models are:

Article:

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  images : []
});
```

User:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    get: escapeProperty
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    get: escapeProperty
  },
 [... etc ...]
```

Comment: Are you using the same version of AngularJS in the fiddle as your actual project? Also in your project code you use the `contains` filter, but your fiddle does not have that. You should post the code for that filter, it is likely the culprit.

Comment: Sadly, we can't help you if the code you show is working. Try to find the problem by progressively reducing the scope of your research.

Comment: I already tested without my second filter and Stil the same pb. I am using angular v1.3.2

Comment: Blackhole, I tried to do this, but here I have quite the same version as on the fiddle. The main difference I see is that I use global $scope (I edit my post with some more info).

Comment: Is there a way to display or test this: filter:{ 'user._id': global.user._id}:true ??

Comment: It's strange because when I test with : art in articles |  filter:{ '1': 1}:true -> It's not working either... There is something I don't understand in this syntax. Shouldn't this work?